# impossible capture sql error with shell script

Tags: sql, shell

I have 2 shell scripts. One with data connection like that (script1.sh):

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
query="$1"
  whenever sqlerror exit 3
  connect $user/$pass@sid
  ${query}
EOF
echo $?
if [ 0 -ne "$?" ]; then
    exit 1
fi
```

and other is a shell script bigger where I execute sql commands like these:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
set -x
$PATH/script1.sh "
--set serveroutput on
--set feedback off
insert into table (column) values ('$1');
commit;
"
if [[ $? != 0 ]]
  then
echo "Error"
exit 3
  else
echo "Ok"
fi
............
..............
```

The problem is that these second script won't detect error in sql commands and always continues with all code. I put traces and I check that rc is always 0.
Could you help me to can detect errors if the sql failed? Thanks!